# Extract date from a long string

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame where the date format is as follows:

```
1:9:Tue Aug 12 2014 19:25:24 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I want to extract three variables day, date and time in three different columns and add it to the data frame

```
Day as Tue
Date as 12/08/2014
Time as 7:25:24PM
```

The first two numbers do not mean anything.

The dataframe consists of over 700,000 rows and I want to the new columns to replace the existing ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be careful about adding the datetime to your data.frame as 3 separate columns, because your 3 columns do not uniquely identify a specific datetime because you do not account for timezone. This shouldn't be a problem if all your datetimes are in the same timezone though.

```
s <- '1:9:Tue Aug 12 2014 19:25:24 GMT+0530 (IST)'
# If the first two numbers do not mean anything and are always separated by a
# colon, then we can remove them with the following gsub command:
s <- gsub("^[[:digit:]:]+","",s)
# Now we can convert the string to a POSIXlt object, assuming they all follow
# the format of including "GMT" before the signed timezone offset
p <- strptime(s, "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z")
```

The above will work even if your datetimes have different timezone offsets. For example:

```
# these times are the same, just in a different timezone (the second is made up)
s <- c('1:9:Tue Aug 12 2014 19:25:24 GMT+0530 (IST)',
       '9:1:Tue Aug 12 2014 19:55:24 GMT+0600 (WAT)')
s <- gsub("^[[:digit:]:]+","",s)
p <- strptime(s, "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z")
# the times are the same
as.POSIXct(p, tz="UTC")
# [1] "2014-08-12 08:55:24 UTC" "2014-08-12 08:55:24 UTC"
```

Formatting the datetimes into the strings you want is easy; just use the format specifications in `?strptime`.

```
data.frame(Day=format(p, "%a"), Date=format(p, "%d/%m/%Y"),
  Time=format(p, "%I:%M:%S%p"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: The answer does not have the date. Can you try to include it in the answer as well ?

Comment: @SuryaPavanPynda: I thought formatting the datetime was trivial, so I did not include it. I just added it.

Answer (score 2):

This was a tough one. R doesn't have the best support for string and date/time functions. But I was able to get it to work with some hacks:

```
str <- '1:9:Tue Aug 12 2014 19:25:24 GMT+0530 (IST)';
fieldsBad <- strsplit(str,':')[[1]];
fields <- c(fieldsBad[1:2],paste0(fieldsBad[3:length(fieldsBad)],collapse=':'));
dt <- strptime(fields[3],'%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S');

df <- data.frame();
df[1,'Day'] <- strftime(dt,'%a');
df[1,'Date'] <- strftime(dt,'%d/%m/%Y');
df[1,'Time'] <- gsub('^0','',strftime(dt,'%I:%M:%S%p'));

df;
```

Shows:

```
  Day       Date      Time
1 Tue 12/08/2014 7:25:24PM
```

Explanation of hacks:

1. Unfortunately, the `strsplit()` function does not allow specifying a maximum number of fields to produce, unlike (for example) http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html in Perl, which has a `LIMIT` argument, which would be perfect here. So I had to sort of "over-split" and then paste the extra fields back together again on colon with `paste0()`.
2. Also, the `strptime()` call ignores the time zone information, although fortunately still parses all it can from the input string. I tried passing the time zone information explicitly to the `tz=` argument, but it wouldn't recognize IST or GMT+0530 or anything I tried. But since you don't seem to require the time zone, we're ok.
3. Finally, no format specifier for `strftime()` seems to allow specifying the 12-hour time without a leading zero, so I had to use `%I` and call `gsub()` to strip it off, if present.

Comment: _"R doesn't have the best support for string & date/time functions."_ er… `lubridate` pacakge, mebbe?

Comment: I've never used `lubridate`, looks like a good package. Good suggestion @hrbrmstr

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

d <- "1:9:Tue Aug 12 2014 19:25:24 GMT+0530 (IST)"
d <- gsub("^[[:alnum:]:]+ ", "", d)
tz <- gsub("[ +-]", "", str_extract(d, " ([[:upper:]]+)[+-]"))

strptime(d, "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S", tz=tz)
## [1] "Aug 12 2014 19:25:24 GMT+0530 (IST)"
```

You'll prbly need to `mapply` that in a data frame context since `strptime` takes an atomic vector for `tz`. So, do something like:

```
dat$parsed <- mapply(as.POSIXct, 
       gsub("^[[:alnum:]:]+ ", "", dat$date),
       format="%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S", 
       tz=gsub("[ +-]", "", str_extract(dat$date, " ([[:upper:]]+)[+-]")))
```

(that'll make `dat$parsed` numeric, but that's what `POSIXct` converts it to, so it's easy to work with)

Answer (score -1):

I realy don't know how to do it in R, but if you get this string from js, you can do something like this:

```
var date = new Date('Tue Aug 12 2014 19:25:24 GMT+0530 (IST)');
console.log(date.getTime());
console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset());
```

get time method will return unix timestamp in ms, and getTimezoneOffset will return timezone offset in minutes. Then, you can parse it using date funcions in R. I hope, it is implemented there.

Comment: I don't think it's parsing the time and time zone correctly. When I add a call of `console.log(date);`, I get `Date {Tue Aug 12 2014 09:55:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}`.

Comment: This is time for your timezone. Think it's ok.

Comment: Oh, ha, you're right. It's parsing correctly, and just displaying the result in my time zone (9.5hr offset from GMT+0530). That's pretty good! Gave you an upvote for your insight.